# Unable to understand this intergration

Tags: integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

[image: how did they do it in just one step?]

I have exams tomorrow. It would be really helpful if someone helps me.
Thank You.

edit : i had tried using the UV rule of integration. but that was getting really lengthy and didn't get any definitive answer. I also tried breaking them down and doing the integration. Again, it was lengthy and the attached image had it done in just one line. So, I came here just to clear this up.
Also, I forgot about the formula that the accepted answer mentioned.

Comment: If you have an exam tomorrow it would be really useful for you to show as much own effort as possible...

Comment: @tired i have tried a lot. and that's why i am here. i am unable to understand this short method. wouldn't be here without trying

Comment: It's helpful by definition if someone helps, so your respective statement is featureless ;)

Comment: What we mean is it would be a lot easier to help you if you could demonstrate what you have done so we can get a good idea of what you are struggling at. The cause of the problem may be something not obvious to you that would become apparent from your approach to the problem.

Comment: @IanMiller ok. now i get it. actually this is my first question here. so i'll keep that in mind for the future questions.

Comment: @tannerjohn Excellent. Learning how to learn is more important than the learning itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $$\int (f (x)+ f'(x))e^x dx = f (x) e^x \tag {1}$$

Here we have $f (x)=\frac {1}{1+x^2} $. Now, let us find the derivative of $f (x) $, that is, $f'(x) $. Using the quotient rule, we have, $$\frac {d}{dx}f (x) = \frac {(1+x^2)\frac {d}{dx}(1)-(1)\frac {d}{dx}(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2} $$ $$=-\frac {2x}{(1+x^2)^2} $$

Now use $(1) $ and we have the result. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By the product rule for differentiation, you have:
$$\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^x\right)'
=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\left(e^x\right)' +  \color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)'}e^x
= \frac{1}{1+x^2}e^x +  \color{blue}{\frac{-2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}}e^x$$
The blue step (derivative) is explained in your notes.

Now note that the right-hand side is exactly the integrand:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^x + \frac{-2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}e^x = \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\right)e^x $$
So you simply have:
$$\int \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\right)e^x \,\mbox{d}x = \int\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^x\right)'\,\mbox{d}x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}e^x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually integrate, you work the other way around using that $$\int_{}^{} f'(x) dx=f(x)+C$$ and differentiate the right hand side. Then you use product rule for differentiation. You get the given result.